# How to split lines into separate variables using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm getting a list of SID numbers using `$list = gwmi win32_userprofile | ft localpath, sid -a` and I want to split each line of the output ($list) into a separate variable. I can't figure out how to do this - any suggestions on the most efficient way? An array? If so, how?

The purpose of this is to then further filter the output to display only SID's that start with S-1-5-21-*, and then assign numbers to each resulting line, allowing the user to select a user SID for domain migration by typing a number.

Comment: can you be more clear please, you want to store each line of the output in an variable or just the line which start S-1-5-21-* ?

Comment: Ultimately yes, each line (there will be multiple lines) that starts with S-1-5-21-* should be stored as a separate variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to format table? This is meant for console output..

Also, a better way to filter would be using the `Where-Object` cmdlet

```
$list = gwmi wi32_userprofile | Where { $_.sid -like "S-1-5-21-*"} | Select localpath, sid
```

Then you can use `$list` like an array.

Comment: Thanks, that works great! I was formatting it so I could see the results easily. Your answer works perfectly!